# How to use Windows 10 style resource in WPF with XAML Islands

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, xaml-islands

I'm using XAML Islands to make my app and I want to use Windows 10 styling in my WPF app like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/typography#using-the-type-ramp). For example `<TextBlock Text="Header" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>` would result in:

[image]

But this doesn't work in WPF (It does work in UWP without any modifications), my understanding is that XAML Islands should make it possible. When I try to simply add the code above to my xaml file I get the exception

> Cannot find resource named 'HeaderTextBlockStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive.

I get the same exception if I add `Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"` to a `<xamlhost:WindowsXamlHost>` element.

So I tried to add the controls with code so I added this WindowsXamlHost control as a stackpanel:

`<xamlhost:WindowsXamlHost InitialTypeName="Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel" ChildChanged="WindowsXamlHost_ChildChanged"/>`

And added this method (an event handler that is ran when the control is made. Learned it from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-standard-control-with-xaml-islands#host-a-calendarview-by-using-the-host-control)) that handles adding additional controls (a TextBlock) to the StackPanel:

```
private void WindowsXamlHost_ChildChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        // Get the host control
        WindowsXamlHost host = (WindowsXamlHost)sender;
        // Get the StackPanel in the host
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel sp = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel)host.Child;
        // Make a TextBlock to add to the StackPanel
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock textBlock = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock();
        // Set the text of the TextBlock
        textBlock.Text = "LockCursorInMonitor";
        // Get the style resources, cast them to the appropriate type for XAML Islands and add them to the TextBlock
        textBlock.Style = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Style)Application.Current.Resources["HeaderTextBlockStyle"];

        // Another way to get resources but this doesn't work too.
        //textBlock.Style = (Windows.UI.Xaml.Style)this.FindResource("HeaderTextBlockStyle");

        // Add the TextBlock to the stackpanel
        sp.Children.Add(textBlock);
    }
```

The `Application.Current.Resources["HeaderTextBlockStyle"]` way does nothing and doesn't throw an exception.

The `this.FindResource("HeaderTextBlockStyle")` way throws the next exception:

> System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException: ''HeaderTextBlockStyle' resource not found.'

So how can I get these style resources in my WPF app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use the package [ModernWPF](https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf) but then you lose all the benefits of XAML Islands (if there are any. Everything I needed from XAML Islands is in ModernWPF and is easier to implement).

After installing and setting ModernWPF up you can simply use the `<TextBlock Text="Header" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>` way and it just works.